# how to rename your localhost/myfolder in htdocs to some domain name

Tags: drupal, xampp

So we all know that to access your site inside htdocs you have to type "localhost/yoursite folder" right? but i have managed to change that by some help of my friend. now my friend is gone so i cant ask him to change it back. Instead of "localhost/yoursite" i can access it through "mysite.test" it has something to do with host.txt in system32. Now the problem is im installing a new drupal site in htdocs again and i cant access it since my localhost is always pointing to my first drupal site. how do i configure this?

HERE'S MY HOST.TXT

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1   activate.adobe.com
    127.0.0.1   drupal6.test
    127.0.0.1   belmark.test
```

drupal 6 is my previous site. and belmark.test is the site i want the localhost to direct to which is not working. even if i omit the drupal6.test line localhost still directs to drupal6.test

and here's my httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin cadaybelmark@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal6"
    ServerName drupal6.test
    ServerAlias drupal6.test
    ErrorLog "logs/drupal6.test-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/drupal6.test-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin cadaybelmark@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal7"
    ServerName belmark.test
    ServerAlias belmark.test
    ErrorLog "logs/drupal.test-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/drupal.test-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i dont know how to elaborate this question further. please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure apache (via xampp) with additional vhosts, one for each site.

A vhost configuration maps a ServerName with a DocumentRoot.  For example,

```
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /path/to/my/drupal
```

If you want a new, second site, you will need a second vhost for it. If you simply want to replace the original site with a new Drupal installation, your original vhost can stay the same (as long as you put in the exact same place as the original, which it sounds like you did not, since the old site is still loading).

See the XAMPP documentation for how to add/edit vhost entries.

Comment: can you help me a little bit here sir. youre the first person to get what i really mean by the question. i understand now about the vhost stuff thanks. Now my problem is that i cant even access localhost now. i will edit my post and include my host.txt

Comment: i can access localhost now. but im back to the main problem again. i cant point localhost to my new site. it always points to my previous site. please sir. need help here

Comment: did you possibly rename the hosts file as hosts.txt? Pretty sure that's not okay.

Comment: @Belmark You did restart XAMPP after changing the vhost file right?

Comment: lol @clive. thanks mate. i figured it out.  yeah you're right.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understood your problem right

create a subfolder in htdocs and install it there.

```
127.0.0.1/subfolder/yoursite
```

Answer (score 0):

My god the answer is so simple. Apache just needs to be restarted. OK! thanks for the efforts guys.